# Where can I find IBM FileNet Content Engine subscription log?

Tags: java, logging, filenet-p8, filenet-content-engine

In my current project using Filenet P8 Content Platform Engine 5.2.1 with WebSphere 8.5.5.3, on a RedHat 6.7 system. I'm wondering where do the subscription is logging.

In my class code I used this configuration for log4j:

```
# Properties for configuring Log4j
# Component
log4j.logger.com.spc.ecm.filenet.action=debug, B

log4j.appender.B=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.B.File=/tmp/filenet_log/spc-add-properties-to document-events.log
log4j.appender.B.MaxFileSize=2MB
log4j.appender.B.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.B.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.B.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} [%-5p] %m%n
```

I think that logs about subscriptions should be located on the back-end side of the P8 installation, but unfortunately I couldn't find them.

Should I have to enable some sort of audit logging?

Comment: Maybe `install_root/profiles/profile_name/FileNet/server_Instance_name/p8_server_error.log`

Comment: Thanks, I was just wondering if it would be possible to have logging about a custom subscription in a specific location. How could it be done?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "logs about subscriptions". If your code writes to `com.spc.ecm.filenet.action` logger, then you should see the output in the configured appender (assuming the above `log4j` configuration is applied). CPE knows nothing about the logger you configured and will not use it.

Comment: I mean that if I insert some logging into the class file implementing the action for debugging, I would like to know where I can find it.

Answer (score 4):

Unless you have specific requirements for logging output, I suggest using facility provided by Content Engine — logging through [com.filenet.api.engine.HandlerCallContext](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNW2F_5.2.1/com.ibm.p8.ce.dev.java.doc/com/filenet/api/engine/HandlerCallContext.html?lang=en). There is a bunch of methods like `traceDetail` or `logError`. The output will be directed to `p8_server_trace.log` or `p8_server_error.log`, which by default are located at `<was root>/profiles/<profile name>/FileNet/<server name>`.

You will find the detailed information on logging in the documentation — [Logging Concepts](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNW2F_5.2.1/com.ibm.p8.ce.dev.ce.doc/logging_concepts.htm?lang=en).